# MongoTemplate Update document with dotted fields

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I've inserted some documents containing dotted field. Dots are converted using configuration.

```
((MappingMongoConverter) mongoTemplate.getConverter())
                                  .setMapKeyDotReplacement("#dot#");

final MyBean bean = networkDataRepository.insert(networkData());

private MyBean networkData() {
    return MyBean.builder().property("dotted.key", true).build();
}
```

Property is a Map

This works.

Now I'd like to update it using :

```
final Update update = new Update();
update.set("properties", ImmutableMap.of("dotted.key", false));
final WriteResult updateFirst = 
             mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, MyBean.class);
```

But this throws an exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Write failed with 
error code 57 and error message 'The dotted field 'dotted.key' 
in 'properties.dotted.key' is not valid for storage.
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Did you get answer to this question?